# Find all solutions of the equation $\cos 2θ + 7 \cos θ = 8$

Tags: trigonometry

Find all solutions of the equation in the interval [0, 2π) (express your answer in terms of $k$, where $k$ is any integer).

$$\cos 2\theta + 7 \cos\theta = 8$$

Did I make a mistake somewhere? My final answer was $0+2\pi k$

Here is my work. I went from step 1 to step 2 by using the trig identity $\cos 2\theta = 2\cos^2\theta -1$ and then solved it like a quadratic. I also set $\cos \theta = x$ because it's easier for me to visualize the equation that way.

[image]

Comment: Why are you so sure that you made a mistake?

Comment: Well because I do homework on webassign which is an online homework thing and you have to submit the answer to the question and it marked it as wrong

Comment: @Tucker it is the one all the way on the bottom http://i.imgur.com/xPb2Jc8.png

Comment: It looks fine to me. You factored correctly, setting one factor equal to zero doesn't give you solutions for $x=cos(\theta)$ for $-1\leq x\leq 1$ and so since you are looking for real valued $\theta$ you do not get solutions. The other factor gives $x=cos(\theta)=1$ which is true for $\theta$ equal to any integer multiple of $2\pi$.

Comment: Observe that your HW wants an answer $\theta$ in the interval $[0,2\pi)$ therefore the only answer is $\theta = 0$ all other answers are not in this range and are not the solutions they want.

Comment: max(7cos(.))=7. the only answer lies in $\theta=0+2\pi i$

Comment: So, your mistake is in not reading the question as carefully as you need to. Understand what they are asking. They didn't want all real values of $\theta$ that satisfy the equation, if they did then your answer would have been correct.

Comment: Cardinal what are you saying?

Comment: Okay so I got $k=0$ which gives me just 0. Update: yup it is correct I was not supposed to put $+2\pi k$ because they didn't want all solutions. Thank you!!!

Comment: An easier way to solve the problem is to note that $\cos \theta \leq 1$ for all $\theta$, with equality holding iff $\theta \in 2\pi \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your final answer is correct $\boxed{\theta=2 \pi n} , \; n \in \mathbb{Z}$

you also have:

$\theta=\bigg(\pi n \pm i \arctan \text{h}\sqrt{\frac{11}{7}}\bigg)$

---

In your homework the interval is $[0,2 \pi)$  so you only have $\boxed0$ as solution

Comment: Thank you, I was adding $+2\pi k$ because I read the problem wrong

Answer (score 0):

Notice, we have $$\cos 2\theta+7\cos \theta=8$$ $$2\cos^2\theta-1+7\cos \theta=8$$ $$2\cos^2\theta+7\cos \theta-9=0$$ $$\underbrace{2\cos^2\theta+9\cos \theta}\underbrace{-2\cos \theta-9}=0$$
$$\cos\theta(2\cos \theta+9)-(2\cos \theta+9)=0$$ $$(\cos \theta-1)(2\cos \theta+9)=0$$ $$\implies \cos\theta-1=0\iff \cos\theta=1=\cos 0$$ Writing the general solution, we get $$\theta=2k\pi\pm 0=2k\pi$$
$$\implies 2\cos\theta+9=0\implies  \cos\theta \neq \frac{-9}{2}$$ this case does not give any solution.

Hence, the general solution of given equation: $\cos 2\theta+7\cos \theta=8$ is $$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{\theta=2k\pi}}$$

Where, $\color{red}{k}$ is any integer.